# How to make graphs in Django (using data from Excel)

Tags: django, python-2.7, graph, charts, graphing

What would be the most efficient way to grab data from Excel/Google Sheets using Python(2.7)/Django and then transform that data into beautiful graphs, charts etc. just like in this [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvy7K.png)?

Best regards,
Daviddep

Answer (score 0):

Use the google docs api/sdk to read the sheet, or save them as .csv.
Read the csv, convert them to json.
Send the json to a javascript library like d3.js to create beautiful graphs

http://d3js.org/

http://datamaps.github.io/

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on that? Frankly, I am quite new to programming, so a more in-depth explanation would help me a lot!

Comment: Just find out bit by bit.
1. how to read a google docs sheet https://developers.google.com/drive/
2. how to save data as json in Python
3. How to build a graph in d3js